# How to 'ALTER VIEW' in HP Vertica

Tags: view

In my new project, I am connecting to HP vertica using **DBeaver**. I have created a view on a large database (about few billion records) with size limit of 300. This view was created to setup other systems in the pipeline. After everything is setup, I want to remove the size limitation of 300 from the view and want to return all the data. Unfortunately, I can only find that command 'ALTER VIEW' for HP Vertica is allowed to simply rename the view and not modify the view itself. I am forced to drop the view and create another one but this breaks the already established data connection from other systems (Tableau) to the original view.

> https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEVIEW.htm

and

> https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/ALTERVIEW.htm

I tried using ALTER VIEW command as in SQL but I get an error -

```
SQL Error [4856] [42601]:
[Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "AS"
[Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "AS"
com.vertica.util.ServerException: 
[Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "AS"
```

Answer (score 1):

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW etc etc.

https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEVIEW.htm